# Can you recommend a book for programming functionality for LaTeX?

Tags: latex

As a LaTeX newbie I want to start using it and extending it with my own stuff. I have some ideas for solutions for technical writing, which aren't solved until now. So I need a good book on LaTeX which looks at it from a programmers point of view. Like how does LaTeX actually work internally, how does all the stuff fit together, and where do I have to start touching code or adding code to get things working. Well you know what I mean right? :)

So is there any good book I should look at?

Comment: Also take a look at Asymptote for graphics.

Comment: Consider "Beginner's book of TeX": http://www.amazon.com/Beginners-Book-TEX-Raymond-Seroul/dp/0387975624/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1261179408&sr=8-3. Also, consider asking one question on the subject instead of seven (7!) when the basic idea is to find general guidance.

Comment: what "technical Writing" problems do you have that are not solved by a latex package? i am a tech writer using latex, and i haven't found anything in the system really lacking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no subsitute for reading the *TeXbook*, which is Don Knuth's original documentation of TeX.  It is a tutorial not a reference, and if you are like most people you will have to read it twice (skipping 'dangerous bends' on the first pass) and do some of the exercises.  Answers to *all* of the exercises are in the back of the book.

You can then move on to the *LaTeX Companion* (I prefer the first edition; subsequent editions are bloated), which has many examples and which has a short "Guide for Class and Package Writers."  The appendices to Lamport's LaTeX manual are also (just barely) useful.

> I need a good book on LaTeX which looks at it from a programmers point of view

LaTeX is only a bunch of hacks piled on top of TeX.  To understand the programming model you *must* read the *TeXbook*—it's the only place that explains how things actually work, the full truth, in detail.  After you master the TeXbook you will be able to read things like the `latex.ltx` source and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Guide to LaTeX by Kopka, Daly instead of the Knuth book because it is more up-to-date, and is very thorough for all features in LaTeX.

Of course, it is not for a complete beginner. Always start from the excellent (and free) guide, The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX2ε

Answer (score 0):

Internals: read Knuth's *The TeX book*. And then Knuth's *TeX: The Program*.

Latex's internals are not very exciting, but the code is free software: you can read it.  But the key is understanding Tex.

Comment: I'd start with **Not so short introduction to LaTeX** for first contact with it. Then, as you say, find Knuth's and Lamport's texts about TeX and LaTeX.